# Definitiones of solid, fluid, and boundary nodes in the context of LBM

Tags: boundary-conditions, lattice-boltzmann-methods

In the family of Lattice Boltzmann (LB) methods, like many others, one deals with three types of node; namely, **fluid node**, **solid node**, and **boundary node**. (I know; the boundary node is a subtype of fluid node.)

1. **What are the exact definitiones of these nodes? (mathematically, or physically)**
2. **What is the type of red node in the figure?**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unless you use specific boundary conditions like an immersed boundary method, the gray part does not exist for the computation after the boundary nodes have been selected. As far as the computation goes, black nodes represent the wall and no other wall exists.

Blue nodes have all degrees of freedom. If you use D2Q9, all 9 propagation directions are used, so mathematically it is the normal LBM equation.

On black nodes, elements that were streamed from directions toward the wall have to be propagated back in another direction as if they bounced on the wall (at least with bounce back boundary conditions).

The red node is exactly as the black ones. Depending on how you decide wich nodes should represent the wall. You may have nodes that actually are inside the wall and still considered as boundary nodes or as it is on your figure, boundary nodes completely outside the wall.

On yellow nodes, unless the boundary is moving, no computation is needed. If you do not want to make an exception for it, yellow nodes can be considered as blue nodes and computation on those nodes will be disregarded. This has no influence.

I hope I've been useful.